# getting autocomplete working

Tags: 7, ajax

I honestly did, what [this](http://drupal.org/node/854216) and [this](http://timonweb.com/how-create-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-drupal-7) tutorial told me, but somehow my autocomplete textfields still fire an ajax error. but to be more specific: the ajax error gives a 200 http response and a status OK, but **no** answer-text.

my setup is:

```
$form['field_new_verein_location_'.$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('<a id="ds_region_new_verein_'.$field_id.'" style="color:black;text-decoration:none;">Neuer Verein Ort</a>'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('description'),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'dsregion/autocomplete'
);

function ds_regions_menu(){
    $items['dsregion/autocomplete']=array(
      'title' => 'location auto complete',
      'page callback' => '_dsregion/autocomplete',
      'access arguments' => array('access region autocomplete'),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}

function _dsregion_autocomplete($string) {
    $matches = array();
    $result = db_select('ds_plz_ort','o')
      ->fields('o',array('ort'))
      ->condition('ort','%'.db_like($string).'%','LIKE')
      ->range(0,10)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAllKeyed();

    foreach($result as $row){
      $matches[$row->ort]=check_plain($row->ort);
    }
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight error in your `page callback` property for the menu item. You've got a string resembling a path in there instead of the name of the callback function.

Just change

```
'page callback' => '_dsregion/autocomplete'
```

to

```
'page callback' => '_dsregion_autocomplete'
```

Then clear Drupal's caches and you should be good to go.

Comment: I love you guys. I was already comparing my code with the ones from the tutorials twice, but I didn't see this. Thanks a lot!